Are "cuWhateverAsync" calls with stream handle NULL universally equivalent to "cuWhatever" calls?
The CUDA Driver API has multiple calls with an "asynchronous" variant, e.g. cuMemcpy2D and cuMemcpy2DAsync, with the "asynchronous" variant taking a stream handle - and there are many more of those.
Is it universally the case, that calling the "non-asynchronous" variant of an API call the same as calling the "asynchronous" variant with nullptr/NULL for the stream handle? i.e. to the extent that one can forego every calling the "non-asynchronous" variants and always use the "asynchronous" ones?
Note: I use parentheses because "asynchronous" calls are not necessarily always completely asynchronous, and "non-asynchronous" calls are sometimes, somewhat, asynchronous. I'm only interested in equivalence of the two kinds of calls.

As far as I see passing 0 for hStream means that it will use the default stream. Why do you think it effectively behaves like the non-async variant ? I haven't read it all, but this gives some info about sync vs async apis.

@wohlstad: 1. You linked to a page regarding the runtime API. 2. The reason I think so is that, AFAICT, all actual-GPU actions of CUDA are eventually scheduled on some kind of driver-managed queue - and I assume that's the default stream if you haven't specified anything else.

You might be right. I am trying to help by means of searching the documentation, I don't have practical expereince with this specific issue. Anyway hopefully this is the relevant page for the driver API. On the face of it it seems like sync vs async is orthogonal to the issue of which stream you use.

Passing 0 for the hStream parameter of the Driver API async functions, is not equivalent to calling the non-async variant of them.
Each API call is performed on a CUDA stream. Passing 0 means that the default stream is used. It is orthogonal to the issue of sync v.s. async API.
There are several differences between sync and async API, but they are not related to a specific stream.
The following description of sync and async API calls is from the Driver API documentation:

Synchronous

For transfers from pageable host memory to device memory, a stream sync is performed before the copy is initiated. The function
will return once the pageable buffer has been copied to the staging
memory for DMA transfer to device memory, but the DMA to final
destination may not have completed.

For transfers from pinned host memory to device memory, the function is synchronous with respect to the host.

For transfers from device to either pageable or pinned host memory, the function returns only once the copy has completed.

For transfers from device memory to device memory, no host-side synchronization is performed.

For transfers from any host memory to any host memory, the function is fully synchronous with respect to the host.


Asynchronous

For transfers between device memory and pageable host memory, the function might be synchronous with respect to host.

For transfers from any host memory to any host memory, the function is fully synchronous with respect to the host.

If pageable memory must first be staged to pinned memory, the driver may synchronize with the stream and stage the copy into pinned
memory.

For all other transfers, the function should be fully asynchronous.



A specific difference between a sync call and and async one with a null stream is given in @RobertCrovella's comment below:
The statement: "For transfers from pinned host memory to device memory, the function is synchronous with respect to the host." (quoted above),  applies to the synchronous version of the API e.g. cudaMemcpy. But it does not apply if you issue the async version - cudaMemcpyAsync into the null stream.

None of what you've quoted suggests a difference between in behavior between a call to cuFoo(args) and a call to cuFooAsync(args, stream_handle). Remember also that streams can be created as concurrent with the default/null stream, on non-concurrent, which corresponds (somewhat?) with synchronicity of behavior.

@einpoklum where in the documentation do you see that the default stream is always synchronous ? As I mentioned I am quite new the issue myself and would be happy to learn.

You're right, I don't see that there, edited my comment.  Still, NVIDIA does say so elsewhere

@einpoklum I still don't understand why you correlate choosing the stream (default or not) with sync vs async. What am I missing here ?

I remember being told that use of the default stream means synchronous behavior; and I have a yet-unfounded assumption that, under the hood, the implementation of cuFoo(args) is simply { return cuFooAsync(args, NULL); }

The presentation in the document will take me some time to digest. Let's see if some other user here will confirm you assumption about  cuFoo(args) being simply { return cuFooAsync(args, NULL); } under the hood.

@einpoklum BTW - I see in the link that I posted that all sync functions use the default stream. But that does not mean that the default stream can only be used synchronously.

@einpoklum I see in the answer that you deleted that you also mention that the default stream can be used async. If this is so - isn't my answer above actually correct (referring to the downvote) ?

Remember my question is not exactly about whether everything is synchronous, but whether the behavior is the same. And, after all, some non-async actions have somewhat-asynchronous behavior (like kernel launches). But I should rephrase my question slightly to emphasize this point.

@einpoklum I see. Anyway reading the documentation again I still have the impression that sync-async is separate (at least in potential) from stream selection. Hopefuly some exprerienced user will confirm or disconfirm it.

@einpoklum Aren't you basically referring to the Legacy default stream behavior? I.e. by specifying the per-thread default stream behavior at compilation time, one can get async behavior using the default stream "which does not synchronize with other streams (just like explicitly created streams)." Synchronous APIs should still be synchronous, and async APIs would therefore behave differently.

@paleonix That may, or may not, be the key to the answer. But - you wrote that "synchronous APIs should still be synchronous"; while actually, they aren't all synchronous even with the "legacy default stream behavior".

We can just concentrate on the situations where behavior is different between the APIs. The issue is that the docs only describe the default stream behavior being about inter-stream synchronization/blocking and not about blocking the host like those old slides do. But I guess that is just a shortcoming of the documentation?

"For transfers from pinned host memory to device memory, the function is synchronous with respect to the host."  Think about that one carefully.  It applies to the synchronous version of the API (e.g. cudaMemcpy).  Does that statement also hold true if you issue a cudaMemcpyAsync into the null stream?  It does not. That is a difference in behavior.  I have already tested it; the documentation lines up with observed behavior.  This answer gave the correct response ("no") and cited relevant documentation.

@RobertCrovella: Your comment answers the question, this answers talks about sync vs. async behavior which is not in itself what I asked. Care to make the comment into an answer?

I think both existing answers cover the bases, and I have upvoted both answers.

@RobertCrovella thanks. And since you do not wish to post an answer, I editted mine and added the info from your comment.

For completion on the answer above: cudaMemcpyAsync will cause as little synchronization as possible, whereas cudaMemcpy may cause a synchronization (based on the type of copy, as mentioned in the answer above). When cudaMemcpy does not cause a synchronization, it will behave as cudaMemcpyAsync was ran on the default stream.
Regarding scheduling any task (kernel launch, cudaMemcpyAsync, etc) on the default stream, it will have 2 effects on stream-ordering:

This task will be dependent on completion of all tasks previously scheduled on a blocking stream
All new tasks scheduled on a blocking stream will be dependent on completion of this task.

You can find more information on stream ordering semantics on this NVIDIA developer blog post, which has nice illustrations that help understand the issue.
Last but not least, starting CUDA 12.1, the CUDA runtime API exposes device flag cudaDeviceSyncMemops, that forces cudaMemcpy and cudaMemset (sync variants) to be fully synchronous. See CUDA runtime documentation for cudaDeviceSetFlags for more information.
